# SQL server stored procedure insert with dynamic exec

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, exec

Am unable to insert record when given all the column names in insert

Below is the SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
@tab_name nvarchar(50),
@tab_id int,
@tab_n nvarchar(50),
@tab_q int
as
Begin
declare @sql as nvarchar(50);
declare @counts as int;

select @sql='select @cnt=count(*) from '+@tab_name+' where id='+cast(@tab_id as varchar)+';'
exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@cnt int output', @cnt=@counts output
```

select @counts as counts

```
if @counts=1
begin
declare @sql1 as nvarchar(50);
select @sql1='update '+@tab_name+' set quantity='+cast(@tab_q as varchar)+'     where id='+cast(@tab_id as varchar)+';'
exec sp_executesql @sql1
end
else
begin
declare @sql2 as nvarchar(50);
set @sql2='insert into '+@tab_name+' (id,name,quantity) values ('+CAST(@tab_id as varchar)+','''+@tab_n+''''
set @sql2+=','+CAST(@tab_q as varchar)+');'
select @sql2
exec sp_executesql @sql2
end
End
```

"

```
command: exec dbo.test @tab_name='inventory',@tab_id=4,@tab_n='chiku',@tab_q=123
```

record gets inserted when column names are removed but does not work with column names during insert.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: declare @sql1 as nvarchar(50)
Is dat long enough for the dynamic query?

Comment: Thanks frederik-de-clercq I made it max and its working.. the error was showing at line 1 of exec command.. was really getting frustrated. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use A nvarchar(max) for dynamic queries with parameters.
Because u never know how long the string can be. unless you know the max lenght of the string.

A dba also told me to use N' as prefix before the string to denote Unicode string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Increase @sql variables size like below:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
....

declare @sql1 as nvarchar(max);
...

declare @sql2 as nvarchar(max);
```